# Accessing Amazon SNS using rest or soap api

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Is there any way to access Amazon SNS using REST or SOAP API, instead of using SDKs.
If there is any way, please suggest me.It will be a huge help for me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The Amazon SNS API is accessible and works using an HTTP protocol. All SDKs are just utility tools to make this communication easier.

As you can see from the [AWS SNS API docs here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html), it is a matter of sending a `POST` request with correctly formulated HTTP Headers and body.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: Notification
x-amz-sns-message-id: da41e39f-ea4d-435a-b922-c6aae3915ebe
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic
x-amz-sns-subscription-arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:2bcfbf39-05c3-41de-beaa-fcfcc21c8f55
Content-Length: 761
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: ec2-50-17-44-49.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent

{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "da41e39f-ea4d-435a-b922-c6aae3915ebe",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic",
  "Subject" : "test",
  "Message" : "test message",
  "Timestamp" : "2012-04-25T21:49:25.719Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "EXAMPLElDMXvB8r9R83tGoNn0ecwd5UjllzsvSvbItzfaMpN2nk5HVSw7XnOn/49IkxDKz8YrlH2qJXj2iZB0Zo2O71c4qQk1fMUDi3LGpij7RCW7AW9vYYsSqIKRnFS94ilu7NFhUzLiieYr4BKHpdTmdD6c0esKEYBpabxDSc=",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:2bcfbf39-05c3-41de-beaa-fcfcc21c8f55"
}
```

You may learn how to sign and build correct requests in their docs (link provided above). So, you don't have to use SDK, and make your own requests. But, I would suggest using the SDK, since it addresses many security issues for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Right now I'm trying to build an app in NativeScript. But SDK is not available right now for nativescript.So i thought of doing it using api calls.

Comment: I'm voting this down since the code example above is not an interaction with SNS's API but it is an HTTP subscription endpoint. This is also cool, but it's not what was asked for

Comment: @BastianVoigt the question was "is there a way to communicate with SNS without SDK" and the answer given is "yes". The example request is an example. The answer would still be valid if there was no example request added.

Comment: I mean no harm. Just think that Adrian Baker's response below is more relevant, because the question refers to accessing SNS via an HTTP based API

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html for example:

```
https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Publish
&TopicArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-east-2%3A698519295917%3AMy-Topic
&Subject=My%20first%20message
&Message=Hello%20world%21 
&Version=2010-03-31
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Where `AUTHPARAMS` is the result of the [AWS Signature Version 4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)